# Php - return count() in words

Tags: php, count, words, human-readable

I have the following in my code:

```
 $my_count = count($total_elements[$array_object]);
```

`$my_count` now contains the number of elements in `$total_elements[$array_object]`. I want to convert this number into its corresponding natural number (zero, one, two, ...)

In this specific case , **I only have 5 numbers**:

```
$numbers  = array(
    2  => 'two',
    3  => 'three',
    4  => 'four',
    5  => 'five',
    6  => 'six',
);
```

How to retrieve the number of elements in a given array and then `echo` the corresponding natural number (human readable number)  from the array? Or better yet - is there a better way of doing this?

(I have found some [functions](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/) or [classes](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/converting-numbers-to-words-in-php/) to do just that - but now those are way too bloated for the simple case I need now)

Now, of course I can do this with `switch()`:

```
switch ($my_count) {
    case 0:
        echo "zero";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "one";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "two";
        break;
      // etc...
}
```

But it just looks so not elegant to me. And also quite stupid if one have more than 10 numbers.

I am sure that there is a more elegant way of achieving that, and even though now I have only 5 numbers, I would like to have some function to re-use in other cases .

(I am sorry if this is a stupid question - but - searching here on SE or Google with keywords `PHP` - `words` and `count()` I only found answers related to counting words in string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only a handful of number:

```
$number = count($yournameit);
$count_words = array( "zero", "one" , "two", "three", "four" );
echo $count_words[$number];
```

Comment: This looks like how the OP already presents it, with shifted indices - although it's missing "five" and "six". (I've still up-voted because it shows *how* to use said look-up.)

Comment: OP said he did not know how to use.. so here it is

Comment: This is so simple , I am embarrassed - I guess I am tired ( still , 3 down votes for this question is strange ).

Answer (score 6):

Pear has a packge for number words.
Check this out [pear Number_word](http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words)

```
$numbers = new Number_Words();
echo $number->toWords(200);
```

It will help you

**EDIT**

You can use [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class in php.

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);  
echo $f->format(200);
```

It will output "Two Hundred"

Comment: +1 Thanks , I have seen it , but current server does not support :-(

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to retrieve 5 numbers, the current approach is fine. Create an associative array containing the numbers as keys and corresponding word as values:

```
$numberArray  = array(
    0  => 'zero',
    1  => 'one',
    2  => 'two',
    3  => 'three',
    4  => 'four',
    5  => 'five',
    6  => 'six',
    // ...
);
```

Now, to retrieve the word corresponding to `$my_count`:

```
$my_count = 2;
echo $numberArray[$my_count]; // => two
```

You could optionally check if the index is defined  using `isset()` before trying to `echo` it. This approach will work for numbers upto 10. However,  this obviously won't work for larger numbers as it requires more complex rules. It isn't easy to create a function that does this in 10 or 20 lines of code. I suggest you use an existing solution instead of trying to create one from scratch. Take a look at the [`Number_Words` PEAR class](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words).

Comment: I think you missunderstood .. I do want the `count()` but I want to output the result in a human readable manner

Comment: No - And it is stated in the original question

Comment: Thanks - It is in fact IMHO more elegant , and I have already adapted @w00d answer to work with my ( associative ) array .But Since I already used `w00d` answer, I would not want to un-accept it . I do however appreciate the help of the good people here :-) . And these answers are always left for future reference ( which is all what SE is about ). Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Theres no quick and easy way to achieve this with an inbuilt php function, however you can do it with this pear package: http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words

Comment: thanks - can not use due to server limitations :-( +1

Answer (score 2):

The PEAR Numbers_Words package provides methods for spelling numerals in words.

**Reference:**

PEAR: http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words

PECL: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php

**Example:**

```
echo number_to_word( '2281941596' );

//Sample output - number_to_word
Two Billion, Two Hundreds Eighty One Million, Nine Hundreds Forty One Thousand and Five Hundreds Ninety Six

//Sample output - PEAR Class
 two billion two hundred eighty-one million nine hundred forty-one thousand five hundred ninety-six
```