# Assigning specific text to a number

Tags: php, string, random, numbers, output

I'm trying to assign text to a number. What I've managed to do so far is for PHP to successfully generate 10 random numbers each time the page is refreshed / opened. All I want to do now is assign a text value to each of the numbers. So for example, 1=Bob 2=Jim 3=Alice, etc. I've seen plenty of people wanting to know how to get numbers in text form (i.e. "one" = 1, "two" = 2, etc), but the methods I've seen don't work for this.

My code I have so far is as follows:

```
<?php

$name = array();

// build a list of ten numbers...

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

// get a 'new' number...

do {
   $number = rand(1,10);
  } while (in_array($number, $name));
 $name[] = $number;
}

echo 'Results:', "\n".join($name, "\n");

?>
```

As it stands, my code above outputs 10 random numbers between 1 and 10, only outputs each number once, and every number in the range has a 100% chance of being output every time. This is important as the purpose of this code is to be used as a random name generator. There are other ways of doing this, but the methods I've tried tend not to conform to this requirement.

There may even be a much easier way of doing this.

Can anyone please help? I'm still trying to learn PHP :)

Thanks

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20309160/

Comment: What do you want the output to be? An array of names to values?

Comment: I want the output to be just the names (so for example: Bob, Jim, Alice, etc) but the order should be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$source = array(1 => "Bob", 2 => "Jim", 3 => "Alice", 4 => "Roman", 5 => "Wiliam", 6 => "Kenneth", 7 => "John", 8 => "Mark", 9 => "Richard", 10 => "Peter");

$name = array();
$numbers = array();

// build a list of ten numbers...
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

// get a 'new' number...
do {
   $number = rand(1,10);
  } while (in_array($number, $numbers));
 $numbers[] = $number;
 $name[] = $source[$number];
}

echo join($name, "\n");
```

Every name of the array $source comes once in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply a random order of names you need you can use `shuffle`:

```
$names = array("Bob","Fred","Tony","Jim");

shuffle($names);

print_r($names);
```